# get mediaSessionID for the current media playing on chrome cast in Swift on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, chromecast

I'm referring to https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/ios/interface_g_c_k_media_status.html#a45e3eb39e674f5d0dbfd78deef77a1e6

that helps me with the api, but the initializer for the GCKMediaStatus class says:
- (instancetype) initWithSessionID:     (NSInteger)     mediaSessionID
mediaInformation:       (GCKMediaInformation *)     mediaInformation

note: this is in Objective-c  syntax but Swift works just the same except in Swift language...

Nonetheless I can't seem to figure out how to retrieve the mediaSessionID to be able to initialize an instance of this class to a new variable.

I'm trying to do the following to get me eventually to the method within this class called streamPosition which would go like this:

```
    var mediaStatus = GCKMediaStatus(sessionID: Int, mediaInformation: GCKMediaInformation!)
    var currentStreamPosition = mediaStatus.streamPosition()
```

where Int would be the mediaSessionID NOT the sessionID of the chrome cast (read the additional section below!!) and GCKMediaInformation! would be an instance of the GCKMediaInformation class. (I think) correct me if I'm wrong on either of those parameters.

Then I could use this data. But when I do this the currentStreamPosition I suppose defaults to 0 and thats what I get when I print to the currentStreamPosition variable.

Note: I've already connected to the current playing media and I am able to pause, play, and seek to an arbitrary number within the stream. This all works. So I now I'm connected and everything else works.

use case: I want to be able skip ahead 15 seconds or rewind 15 seconds etc. with the use of this method, but I haven't found anything to help.

also - don't get sessionID confused with mediaSessionID!! I CAN get the sessionID successfully and print it out. My issue is with the mediaSessionID.

additional info: the autocomplete is Xcode says this is the parameters labeled names:

```
    GCKMediaStatus(sessionID: Int, mediaInformation: GCKMediaInformation!)
```

note the first parameter says sessionID and it is of type int. But on https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/ios_sender if you notice sessionID is of type String! (an optional String).

I think this label was mis-named in Xcode for the autocomplete. I think it should be named mediaSessionID and NOT sessionID since this is what the documentation shows on the first link I provided.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Seems to me you already have a reference to GCKMediaControlChannel (which, presumably, you use to play/pause/... the media). If that is the case, then you can get a reference to the GCKMediaStatus through mediaStatus property of  GCKMediaControlChannel. Is that what you want to get a hold of?

Comment: @AliNaddaf very clever... you're right, but when I do mediaControlChannel!.pause() <- that works then: var temp = mediaStatus?.streamPosition "temp" is nil so I'm not initializing correctly I guess. I'm not sure

Comment: I suggest you look carefully at the reference sample app CastVideos-ios (https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-ios) to see how these things are dealt with.

Answer (score 0):

To get the stream position, use the method [approximateStreamPosition](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/ios/interface_g_c_k_media_control_channel.html#a0108b52f99f28cfe6052e0486260add2) on GCKMediaControlChannel.

Comment: This worked. Thank you! Very weird I couldn't use streamPosition